# How to allow all filetype upload

Tags: php, file, upload

I don't find a way to avoid filetype limit filter when i upload.
Is there a way to upload all file type with this script?

It filters only image file type upload... i need to allow all file type

```
$code = $_POST['code'];
$dts = $_POST['dts'];
$ttt = explode(',',$dts);
$others_image_last='';
$image_link="/storage2/"; //folder name
 for($i=0; $i<sizeof($_FILES['upload_files']['name']); $i++) {
if (in_array($i+1, $ttt)){}else{     
$new_file = md5(microtime());
$image_type = $_FILES["upload_files"]["type"][$i];
$image_name = $_FILES["upload_files"]["name"][$i];
$image_error = $_FILES["upload_files"]["error"][$i];
$image_temp_name = $_FILES["upload_files"]["tmp_name"][$i];

if (($image_type == "image/jpeg") || ($image_type == "image/png") || ($image_type == "image/pjpeg") || ($image_type == "image/jpg")) {
    $test = explode('.', $image_name);
    $name = $new_file.'.'.end($test);
    $url = '.'.$image_link. $name;
    $info = getimagesize($image_temp_name);
         if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_temp_name);
    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') $image = imagecreatefromgif($image_temp_name);
    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') $image = imagecreatefrompng($image_temp_name);
    imagejpeg($image,$url,80);
} 

$query = "INSERT INTO storage(flname,file_type,usercode) VALUES('".$image_name."','".$image_type."','".$code."')";
$res = mysql_query($query);

$queryfile= "UPDATE routing SET file_up='1' WHERE code ='".$code."'";
$resfile = mysql_query($queryfile);  

echo $name;


}
}
```

Comment: The code is *explicitly* checking the file types and only performing certain operations for certain types.  If you don't want to perform that check, have you tried removing it?  What exactly isn't working as expected?

Comment: It would seem easy enough to just remove what's inside the `if (($image_type == "image/jpeg") ...) {` condition. You would have to use [`move_uploaded_file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) though. Other than that, *your snippet is vulnerable to SQL injections. Use prepared statements.*

Comment: Are you unfamiliar with what an `if` statement does in PHP? You can clearly see the bit where it checks the file types.

Comment: This script has various other serious security problems and also various logic errors though too. Not sure where you got it from, but I'd throw it away and start again.

Comment: @MarkusAO can you edit my script with your suggestions?

Comment: @ADyson i've tried to delete if statements and elseif too but then it doesn't upload on the server...

Comment: Well you're not running move_uploaded_ file anywhere to save the file permanently (as mentioned by another commenter above). Like I said, the script more generally is a piece of junk and very obsolete. It doesn't seem to actually create any meaningful link between the uploaded image and the database entry anyway, even in its current form.

Comment: Why are you using the obsolete `mysql_` code library? It was discontinued in PHP 5.5 (2013) and removed entirely in PHP 7 (2015). No apps should still be using it. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` (both released in the 2000s!) as soon as possible, and learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Comment: Also, if you are running `mysql_` queries successfully, it shows you are running an unsupported version of PHP. You should upgrade your PHP version urgently to continue to receive security updates. https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: @marco77sa: It honestly sounds like what you're looking for is a Google search for "upload file in PHP" or something similar.  There are many simple examples of how to receive a posted file in PHP and save it.  From the question and comments it seems pretty clear that you don't understand the code you're showing us and probably just found it somewhere.  To write, modify, or in general understand any code is going to take some patience and effort on your part.  Learn the basics of PHP, start with simple examples, build your attempt one feature at a time.